# Prove $\liminf a_n + \liminf b_n\le \liminf (a_n +b_n) $

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

$a_n$ and $b_n$ are two bounden sequences 
Prove 
$$\liminf(a_n) + \liminf(b_n)\le \liminf(a_n +b_n)$$

Should I use 
$$\inf(a+b) = \inf(a) + \inf(b)$$ and i could not come up with how to proceed from this. Or should i use a different approach?

Comment: @SuzuHirose it is the $\liminf$ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior.

Comment: liminf means limit infimum when I say $lim inf(a_n)$ I mean limit infimum of $a_n$

Comment: @SuzuHirose, is the lim inf of a *sequence* .

Comment: @Bob, the original post wasn't clear at all. Also, those round parentheses didn't help.

Comment: Sorry about that I write the question from the phone. Edits will be appreciated

Comment: @Travis I don't agree that it is a duplicate, though it is closely related. One can mimick the proof there, or reduce the present case to the lim sup case by the judicious application of some minus signs.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Yes, one could well argue that. My view is that any student who knows enough analysis to the ask the question would immediately see the two questions as essentially identical.

Comment: is the given inequality ,$$\liminf(a_n) + \liminf(b_n)\le \liminf(a_n +b_n)$$ valid only for bounded sequence,or also true for unbounded sequence?

Answer (score 1):

Let us write
$$
\liminf u_n = \sup_{N}\inf_{n>N}u_n
$$

When you replace $u_n$ with $a_n + b_n$ you get successively:
$$ m>N\implies 
a_m + b_m \ge \inf_{n>N} a_n + \inf_{n>N} b_n
\\
\inf_{n>N} [a_n + b_n] \ge \inf_{n>N} a_n + \inf_{n>N} b_n
\\
\inf_{n>N} [a_n + b_n] \ge \sup_N\inf_{n>N} a_n + \inf_{n>N} b_n\\
\sup_N\inf_{n>N} [a_n + b_n] \ge \sup_N\inf_{n>N} a_n + \inf_{n>N} b_n
$$